# Is the closure of a quasi-affine variety affine?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

**some definitions**

We work over a fixed algebraically closed field $k$.And $A^{n}$ is an affine n-space over $k$,i.e. $A^{n}=k^{n}$.

An **affine variety** is an irreducible algebraic set in $A^{n}$.An open subset of an affine variety is called a **quasi-affine variety**.

My question:

**Let $Y$ be a quasi-affine variety,is its closure $\bar Y$ an affine variety?**

Here is my argument: Since Y is irreducible,so is $\bar Y$.Also,$\bar Y$ is closed,hence $\bar Y$ is an affine variety.

Is my argument correct? Am I missing something?

Any help will be greatly appreciated,thanks!

Comment: If $Y$ is a quasi-affine variety, then it's the open set of some affine variety $X$ so $\overline Y$ is just $X$ right?

Comment: This looks OK to me. You may want to say a few words about why $Y$ irreducible implies the closure is irreducible.

Comment: @AlfredYerger I know the reason on why $\bar Y$ is irreducible,just check by definition.I just want to determine whether my argument is true or not ?

Comment: Well, a variety is a closed and irreducible subset. You've shown it's closed, and you've shown it's irreducible.

Comment: @Ravi Yes.Since any non-empty open set of an irreducible topological space is dense and irreducible.

Comment: Then that line is all you really need.